# Grouped data to Pandas Multi-Index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

I have some data in Excel that's already laid out in groups (it's a Statement of Cash Flows from some accounting software) that I'm reading into Pandas with the `read_excel()` method.  I want to create an index on the first 4 columns, but I can't figure out how to maintain the hierarchy of accounts.  Here's what the hierarchy looks like:

[image: Data in Excel]

When I try to either create a multi-index from the first 4 columns or if I do a `ffill()` on them, Pandas (effectively) does this...

[image: Incorrect Multi-Index or ffill() result]

The highlighted cells are incorrect for what I need and they should be blank/NaN to maintain the hierarchy.  When the subcategory B2 on Level 2 starts, any categories from levels 3 and 4 should not be filled.

Here's what I'm trying to achieve:

[image: Expected result]

Ultimately, these are Statements of Cash Flows from multiple years that have slightly different charts of accounts, so my hope was to import them into Pandas DataFrames and merge them so the accounts all line up across the whole time period... this is just the first step in the process.  I could code this into a dictionary manually, but am wondering if it's possible more simply within Pandas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here a way by reversing columns order and `cumprod` on `isna`:

Given df,

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Level 1':['A1']+['']*7,
                  'Level 2':['']+['B1']+['']*3+['B2']+['']*2,
                  'Level 3':['']*2+['C1']+['']*3+['C2']+[''],
                  'Level 4':['']*3+['D1','D2']+['']*2+['D3'],
                  'DataCol1':['']*3+['Value1', 'Value3']+['']*2+['Value5'],
                  'DataCol2':['']*3+['Value2', 'Value4']+['']*2+['Value6']})
```

Input dataframe:

```
  Level 1 Level 2 Level 3 Level 4 DataCol1 DataCol2
0      A1                                          
1              B1                                  
2                      C1                          
3                              D1   Value1   Value2
4                              D2   Value3   Value4
5              B2                                  
6                      C2                          
7                              D3   Value5   Value6
```

Replace '' with np.nan:

```
df_nans = df.replace('', np.nan)
```

Create a boolean array, reverse the columns, cumprod on isna; this will be 1 for all NaN until the first non-NaN value then will become 0 after that.  And reverse again to reorder columns.

```
mask_frame = df_nans.loc[:,::-1].isna().cumprod(axis=1).loc[:, ::-1].astype(bool)
print(mask_frame)
```

Boolean dataframe:

```
   Level 1  Level 2  Level 3  Level 4  DataCol1  DataCol2
0    False     True     True     True      True      True
1    False    False     True     True      True      True
2    False    False    False     True      True      True
3    False    False    False    False     False     False
4    False    False    False    False     False     False
5    False    False     True     True      True      True
6    False    False    False     True      True      True
7    False    False    False    False     False     False
```

Forwards fill df_nans and mask values:

```
df_out = df_nans.ffill().mask(mask_frame)
```

Output:

```
  Level 1 Level 2 Level 3 Level 4 DataCol1 DataCol2
0      A1     NaN     NaN     NaN      NaN      NaN
1      A1      B1     NaN     NaN      NaN      NaN
2      A1      B1      C1     NaN      NaN      NaN
3      A1      B1      C1      D1   Value1   Value2
4      A1      B1      C1      D2   Value3   Value4
5      A1      B2     NaN     NaN      NaN      NaN
6      A1      B2      C2     NaN      NaN      NaN
7      A1      B2      C2      D3   Value5   Value6
```

And, fillna with '',

```
df_out.fillna('')
```

Output:

```
      Level 1 Level 2 Level 3 Level 4 DataCol1 DataCol2
0      A1                                          
1      A1      B1                                  
2      A1      B1      C1                          
3      A1      B1      C1      D1   Value1   Value2
4      A1      B1      C1      D2   Value3   Value4
5      A1      B2                                  
6      A1      B2      C2                          
7      A1      B2      C2      D3   Value5   Value6
```

Comment: I've been programming in Python for probably 8 years and have prided myself on only ever having to ask one SO question in that time;  I've always been able to figure it out.  But I'm somewhat new to Pandas and this one had me befuddled.  Slick answer - I wasn't aware of cumprod or mask.  I know we're not supposed to write "thanks" comments, but what the heck - thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

I have a simple utility function for this:

```
def fillright(row, cols=None, text='DUMMY'):
    """ If empty or NaN, fill given columns to the right with 'text'. """ 
    filling = False
    for c in cols:
        if row[c] is np.nan or row[c]=='':
            if filling==True:
                row[c] = text
        else:
            filling = True
    return row
```

```
levels = ['Level 1','Level 2','Level 3','Level 4']
df.apply(fillright, cols=levels, axis=1 )
```

Intermediate result:

```
  Level 1 Level 2 Level 3 Level 4 DataCol1 DataCol2
0      A1   DUMMY   DUMMY   DUMMY                  
1              B1   DUMMY   DUMMY                  
2                      C1   DUMMY                  
3                              D1   Value1   Value2
4                              D2   Value3   Value4
5              B2   DUMMY   DUMMY                  
6                      C2   DUMMY                  
7                              D3   Value5   Value6
```

Now we do a regular ffill and then get rid of the dummy text:

```
df[levels] = ( df[levels]
    .replace('', np.nan)
    .fillna( method='ffill' )
    .replace('DUMMY', '')
)
```

Which produces the desired result.